# Android Intent.ACTION_SEND handling back action

Tags: java, android, android-activity, share

I have a bug in my app and I didnt find anyone talking about the same problem.

This is how I am creating my intent:

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareContent);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bmpUri);
shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT);
shareIntent.setType("image/*");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Image"));
```

And this works fine, the problem is that if I try to return to my app, it is not responding back. How do I solve that?

I tried using:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

But this doesn't solve my problem.

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this?

This is my logcat:

```
Caught a RuntimeException from the binder stub implementation.
                                                                          java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.os.IBinder com.mediatek.anrappmanager.IFrameworks.serviceManagerGetService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                              at com.mediatek.anrappmanager.ANRManagerNative$1.b(SourceFile:77)
                                                                              at com.mediatek.anrappmanager.ANRManagerNative$1.c(SourceFile:75)
                                                                              at com.mediatek.anrappmanager.ANRManagerNative$a.get(SourceFile:97)
                                                                              at com.mediatek.anrappmanager.ANRManagerNative.getDefault(SourceFile:35)
                                                                              at com.mediatek.anrappmanager.ANRAppManager.dumpMessageHistory(SourceFile:59)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread.dumpMessageHistory(ActivityThread.java:1244)
                                                                              at android.app.ApplicationThreadNative.onTransact(ApplicationThreadNative.java:682)
                                                                              at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:451)
```

Comment: what does `it is not responding back` mean exactly, is it frozen, invisible, ...?

Comment: Also, please explain what "this is not working either" means.

Comment: @mjn - the screen is all black and after a while (like 2-4 minutes) I get a message that my app stopped responding and if I wish to close it. I would post a screenshot, but it is in portuguese

Comment: @CommonsWare - I tried that but it doesnt solve my problem. (That was one of the solutions I found online).

Answer (score 1):

Delete this line:-

```
shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT);
```

When you flag the intent as a new intent, it causes a logical break in your application.You do this when you want to show the next activity being launched separately in your recent apps section.

Comment: This was actually me trying to fix it. It doesnt work without this line either :(. Thanks for your reply tho